# Set which geometry shader to use in DirectX11?

Tags: directx-11

For all the other shaders there is a VSSetShader or PSSetShader function in the device context but I don't see the equivalent for the geometry shader. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`ID3D11DeviceContext::GSSetShader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476438(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Keep in mind that you need a ``D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0`` or greater device to actually use the Geometry Shader.